# how to display array of http response in angular2 cli?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

```
  timehours: any[]=[{name: '--sel--', hrsv:0}, {name: '1 Hr', hrsv: 12000}, {name: '2 Hr', hrsv: 2}, {name: '3 Hr', hrsv: 3}, {name: '4 Hr', hrsv: 4},{name: '5 Hr', hrsv: 5}];
```

Above is my custom defined array and i displayed this in a template easily without any problem.

When i'm trying to view an array from soap response, nothing is displayed in template. I got this error `<!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": null
}-->`

[a response array what i'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oumot.png)
 in console. This is my template . How do i fix it?

```html
<ul class="listboxtickets">
          <li class="selectlistticket" *ngFor="let tick of ticketlists">
            <div class="atickid"> {{tick.id}}  </div>
            <div class="atickname"> {{tick.summary}} </div>
            <div class="atickstat"> <img class="staraimg" src="assets/images/star_icon.png"/> </div>
          <div class="namelinet"> <img src="assets/images/text_bottomline.png"/> </div>
        </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Can you post your component and template code?

Comment: You must post your template, http-request, component code regarding this issue, no one can help you with this little information ;)

Comment: @praveenkumars, really not yet enough information, `ng-for-of null` suggests your response you are getting is null. So have you checked your network tab that you are actually receiving anything from the api?

Comment: Please post your template, http request and component method for this issue as well as the JSON you are receiving, THEN we might be able to help ;)

Comment: Better, but STILL not enough information. How does the actual JSON response look like (in your network tab), and how do you handle the response (http, map, subscribe)?

Comment: it's actually an ajax soap call, i make it as a json data using json.parse method

Comment: Well, with this little information, I cannot help. You need to provide more code, as I have asked, how your data looks like, how you manipulate it, how your component code looks like etc. Everything related to reproduce this issue. Now we just have a picture of data and the template where you try and iterate the data, which clearly is null according to your error. So somewhere you are assigning wrong data to your array, but I don't know where since you have not shown all relevant code ;)

Comment: @AJT_82 yeah...i made a mistake in ajax success call.But i don't know how to solve this. I was initially made an array variable as public. And it's not accessible inside ajax success call. It's really a problem of mine. That's y it's showing null to me. Is there any options to use public variable inside ajax success call?

Comment: Inside ajax call typescript variables couldn't updated.Initially i was assuming an array public tickets : any[];    then inside ajax call   i use this like ....success: function (soapResponse) {   this.tickets = soapResponse; }

Comment: finally i got a solution....any way thanks a lot for your immediate reply... "context: this" gave a result to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery.soap is the best way to solve this problem which is only available at npm for angular2. "context: this" gave a result to me

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `json` pipe to display the data like so:

```
{{ data | json }}
```

This will display the data as text. Additionally, you can use the `<pre>` tag to get a pretty view of the data like so:

```
<pre>{{ data | json }}</pre>
```

## [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/NkmCP0Whz3n8GsCeP9NP)

Comment: i got this in my binding html area <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": null
}-->

Comment: It should be able to display the data for an array as well. I am not sure what your second comment means.

Comment: When i tried to display a custom array it becomes fine.But comes to http json response,it shows nothing in html view...it shows null. But in console i got my all the data in a array format such like my custom array. Can u please help me to  resolve this?

Comment: I do not have enough info about your system to help you identify your exact issue but I updated my demo to show displaying data from an HTTP call as well.